# Delete numbers at the beginning of lines

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file "file.txt" in which some rows begins with numbers.

E.g. file.txt:

```
1 bla bla 390
23 foo foo 100
# bar bar 

some word

45 junk
```

Is there an easy and fast way to delete the numbers (and the space) from all the lines
that start with a number, while deleting only the space from the others?

I would like a command so that the file then looks like:

```
bla bla 390
foo foo 100
# bar bar 

some word

junk
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the command editor line:

```
:%s/^\d*//
```

This uses the global search `%s` to find any line that begins with a digit `\d*` and replace it with nothing `//`.

Additionally, if you need to remove the extra space after the number as well:

```
:%s/^\d* //
```

Comment: If you exported your history to file, you need to remove the extra space before and after the digits: `:%s/^[ ]*\d*[ ]\+//`

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression works in geany, just use `replace in document`

```
^([\d]+ +)|^( +)
```

it gives your desired output for the input below

```
1 bla bla 390
23   foo foo 100
# bar bar 

  some word

45 junk
```